# Product purchases - if consumer buys product x how likely are they to buy product y

Tags: r

I have some data on store level purchases, a random sample of the data looks like the following:

```
      PANID       WEEK    L1
966 3357632 2011-02-21 PIZZA
352 3357632 2009-11-09 SALTY
68  3357632 2012-06-18  BEER
65  3357632 2012-03-05  BEER
43  3108696 2011-10-31  BEER
672 3144766 2010-03-29 SALTY
70  3357632 2012-06-18  BEER
810 3144766 2012-06-18 SALTY
546 3144766 2008-05-05 SALTY
933 3357632 2009-06-15 PIZZA
```

(EDIT: This random sample contains 2012 info, the data I provided was filtered from 2007 - 2010 - due to character count)

There are 3 `PANID`s across 4 years worth of data for 3 categories of products (`BEER`, `SALTY`, `PIZZA`). I am trying to find out whether people who bought `BEER` on a given week also bought `SALTY` / construct a probability that given that `PANID: 3144766` bought `SALTY` in `WEEK: 2009-06-15` what is the probability that they will also by `BEER`. Doing the same for `pizza`, i.e. given that they bought `BEER` the probability of them buying `PIZZA` and finally given that they bought `PIZZA` the probability of them buying `SALTY`.

E.G. the person below bought 3 packets of `SALTY` and one unit of `BEER` but on a different week they would have just bought `BEER` and `PIZZA` or just `SALTY`.

```
> data %>%
+   group_by(PANID) %>%
+   filter(WEEK == "2009-06-15") %>%
+   filter(PANID == "3144766")
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   PANID [1]
    PANID WEEK       L1   
    <int> <date>     <chr>
1 3144766 2009-06-15 BEER 
2 3144766 2009-06-15 SALTY
3 3144766 2009-06-15 SALTY
4 3144766 2009-06-15 SALTY
5 3144766 2009-06-15 PIZZA
6 3144766 2009-06-15 PIZZA
```

Data:

EDIT1: Data removed due to character limit. Can be found here: https://textuploader.com/db1kf

EDIT2:

I run the following code to get the below output:

```
#Probability of buying BEER or SALTY if PIZZA was bought
dat %>% 
  group_by(PIZZA > 0) %>% 
  summarise(beer = sum(BEER > 0) / n(), nobeer = sum(BEER == 0) / n(),
            salty = sum(SALTY > 0) / n(), nosalty = sum(SALTY == 0) / n())

#Probability of buying SALTY or PIZZA if BEER was bought
dat %>% 
  group_by(BEER > 0) %>% 
  summarise(pizza = sum(PIZZA > 0) / n(), nopizza = sum(PIZZA == 0) / n(),
            salty = sum(SALTY > 0) / n(), nosalty = sum(SALTY == 0) / n())


#Probability of buying BEER or PIZZA if SALTY was bought
dat %>% 
  group_by(SALTY > 0) %>% 
  summarise(pizza = sum(PIZZA > 0) / n(), nopizza = sum(PIZZA == 0) / n(),
            beer = sum(BEER > 0) / n(), nobeer = sum(BEER == 0) / n())
```

Output:

```
1)

# A tibble: 2 x 5
  `PIZZA > 0`  beer nobeer salty nosalty
  <lgl>       <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 FALSE       0.333  0.667 0.833   0.167
2 TRUE        0.257  0.743 0.586   0.414

2)

# A tibble: 2 x 5
  `BEER > 0` pizza nopizza salty nosalty
  <lgl>      <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 FALSE      0.371   0.629 0.843   0.157
2 TRUE       0.290   0.710 0.532   0.468

3)

# A tibble: 2 x 5
  `SALTY > 0` pizza nopizza  beer nobeer
  <lgl>       <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 FALSE       0.569   0.431 0.569  0.431
2 TRUE        0.272   0.728 0.219  0.781
```

Just so my understanding is correct. If I buy `PIZZA` I have a `0.586` probability of buying `SALTY` and a `0.414` probability of not buying `SALTY` (table 1). However if I buy `SALTY` then I would have a `0.272` probability of buying `PIZZA` and a `0.728` of not buying `PIZZA` (table 3)?

Comment: This seems to be more a question on statistical analysis (what do you need to do to calculate the probability) than it is a question in R (how do you code R to do the thing you need to do to calculate the probability).

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to do. Calculate the conditional probability that given person X bought product `BEER` what the probability that same person (on the same shopping trip `WEEK`) will put product `SALTY` in their basket. - suggesting that beer and salty products are compliments and should have a higher probability of being combined than other products in the dataset i.e. `DIAPERS`.

Comment: I'm just saying this is a statistics question, not an R question. Anyway hint re the R part: `df %>% group_by(PANID, year, WEEK,L1) %>% summarize(n=n()) %>% tidyr::spread(L1, n)`

Comment: Thats quite helpful, thanks! This gives me the total purchases each consumer made for each product on a given `WEEK`?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you're looking for, so let me know if I'm off track.

We start with what I suggested in the comment (slightly adjusted to replace the NAs with 0):

```
df<- df %>% group_by(PANID, year, WEEK,L1) %>% summarize(n=n()) %>% tidyr::spread(L1, n, fill=0)
```

This gives us a wide-data format where for each person-week, we see the number of purchases of each of the three food types, e.g.:

```
> head(df,3)
# A tibble: 3 x 6
# Groups:   PANID, year, WEEK [3]
    PANID  year WEEK        BEER PIZZA SALTY
    <int> <int> <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 3108696  2007 2007-12-31     2     4     6
2 3108696  2008 2008-01-21     0     2     2
3 3108696  2008 2008-02-04     1     0     2
```

Now we can create a table that gives the probability for buying either BEER or SALTY (of any amount) if PIZZA (of any amount) was purchased in the same week:

```
df %>% group_by(PIZZA>0) %>% 
  summarise(beer=sum(BEER>0)/n(),nobeer=sum(BEER==0)/n(),
    salty=sum(SALTY>0)/n(),nosalty=sum(SALTY==0)/n())
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  `PIZZA > 0`  beer nobeer salty nosalty
  <lgl>       <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 FALSE       0.333  0.667 0.833   0.167
2 TRUE        0.257  0.743 0.586   0.414
```

So we can see that if Pizza was purchased, the likelihood of both beer and salty goes down compared to weeks when pizza is not purchased.

The same can be done for BEER and SALTY, of course.

An alternative, since we have a numerical variable for each of the three foods, would be to calculate correlation or even regression, but that's not what you asked for.

Comment: Yes I believe this is what I was hoping for. The regression will be the next step. I have made an edit to my original post regarding the understanding of the output probabilities.

Comment: Great. Don't forget to accept! Re your question - yes, your interpretation is correct. How this happens may be clearer if you look at the absolute numbers, by removing all the `/n()`s from the code.